# Improve stored procedure performance in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a source table with a below sample data set:

```
systemuid     filename           mindatetime                 maxdatetime
  70277     monitor_1.dat   2019-04-21 08:00:00 AM      2019-04-21 03:10:00 PM
  10006     monitor_2.dat   2019-04-25 10:00:00 AM      2019-04-25 11:30:00 AM
  10006     monitor_3.dat   2019-04-28 08:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 10:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_3.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 11:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_3.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 04:00:00 PM
  8368      monitor_1.dat   2019-05-21 11:00:00 AM      2019-05-21 11:30:00 AM
```

I am writing a stored procedure using cursors to take care of a business scenario. The procedure has the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DELETE_REDUNDANT_RECORDS_STORED_PROCEDURE
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
    interval_time            BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    min_time                 BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    max_time                 BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    rec_old                  RECORD;
    rec_new                  RECORD;
    rec_start                RECORD;
    v_filename               VARCHAR(250);
    v_systemuid              VARCHAR(50);
    is_continous_record      BOOLEAN default false;

    cursor_file CURSOR FOR
        SELECT distinct filename,systemuid FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TESTING;

    cursor_data CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TESTING WHERE filename = v_filename AND systemuid=v_systemuid ORDER BY mindatetime, maxdatetime;

BEGIN
    -- Use cursors for iteration
    -- Business logic to delete and update the table records based on certain conditions

    OPEN cursor_file;
    LOOP
        FETCH cursor_file into v_filename, v_systemuid;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            -- raise notice 'filename and systemuid %, %' , v_filename, v_systemuid;
            -- Open the second cursor to get the records for a given filename and systemuid
            OPEN cursor_data;
            -- Put the first record in rec_old
            FETCH cursor_data INTO rec_old;
            -- Keep a reference to this record and store it in rec_start
            rec_start = rec_old;
            LOOP
                -- Put the second record to rec_new
                FETCH cursor_data INTO rec_new;
                min_time = extract(epoch from rec_new.mindatetime) * 1000;
                max_time = extract(epoch from rec_old.maxdatetime) * 1000;

                -- Make sure the second record's mindatetime is greater than first record's maxdatetime
                if min_time > max_time then
                    interval_time :=   min_time - max_time;
                else
                    interval_time := null;
                end if;

                -- Condition to find the continuous records having a time difference of 1 millisecond
                IF interval_time is not null  AND interval_time = 1 THEN
                    INSERT INTO BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TEMP(systemuid,filename,mindatetime,maxdatetime,filename) VALUES (rec_old.systemuid,rec_old.filename, rec_old.mindatetime, rec_old.maxdatetime,null);
                    rec_old = rec_new;
                    is_continous_record = true;
                ELSE
                    if is_continous_record then
                        INSERT INTO BOOKMARK.MONITORING_TEMP(systemuid,filename,mindatetime,maxdatetime,fileid) VALUES (rec_old.systemuid,rec_old.filename, rec_start.mindatetime, rec_old.maxdatetime,uuid_generate_v4());
                        INSERT INTO BOOKMARK_AUDIT.MONITORING_AUDIT(systemuid,filename,mindatetime,maxdatetime,updated_fileid) VALUES (rec_old.systemuid,rec_old.filename, rec_old.mindatetime, rec_old.maxdatetime,null);
                        is_continous_record = false;
                    end if;
                    EXIT WHEN interval_time is null;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
            -- Close the second cursor
            CLOSE cursor_data;
        -- Some operations to insert/delete records goes here
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_file;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**What the procedure is doing**

The first cursor is used to fetch the distinct systemuid and filename from the source table and then in the second cursor I have to fetch all the records for that given systemuid and filename to perform some computations based on business needs.

**Problem:**

The program works fine when the data set is small like around *1 million* records but beyond *4-5 million records* the procedure starts taking a lot of time (*around 4-5 hours*) for completion. I have an index also on the table on columns systemuid and filename.

1. How can I handle the performance of the program?
2. Is there a better
       way to declare my cursor queries to improve performance as the
       source table will grow and contain around *100 million records* in
       future?

Comment: Without showing us the actual code that uses the cursors it's nearly impossible to answer. In general cursors should be avoided to begin with and replaced with a set based approach.

Comment: There is no way to speed up the first query; it has to perform a full sequential scan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added some part of the logic for your understanding